# Problem with line breaking citation with bibtex

Tags: line-breaking, natbib

I'm having troubles with the the appropriate line breaking of my references with BibTeX with the author-date format.

The problem is that each reference is cited in the format "`(Author, Year)`". When the citation is at the end of the line, LaTeX is breaking the line with the comma at the beginning of the next line, e.g., "`(Author \\, year)`" when the appropriate way would be "`(Author, \\ year)`".

Here is a MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @article{Mathur2007,
    title={Uncovering the Lagrangian skeleton of turbulence},
    author={Mathur, Manikandan and Haller, George and Peacock, Thomas and Ruppert-Felsot, Jori E and Swinney, Harry L},
    journal={Physical review letters},
    volume={98},
    number={14},
    pages={144502},
    year={2007},
    publisher={APS}
  }
  @article{Miranda2013,
   author = {Miranda, Rodrigo a and Rempel, Erico L and Chian, Abraham C-L and Seehafer, Norbert and Toledo, Benjamin a and Mu\~{n}oz, Pablo R},
    journal = {Chaos (Woodbury, N.Y.)},
    month = sep,
    number = {3},
    pages = {033107},
    title = {{Lagrangian coherent structures at the onset of hyperchaos in the two-dimensional Navier-Stokes equations.}},
    volume = {23},
    year = {2013}
  }
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[inner=3.0cm,outer=3.0cm,top=3.0cm,bottom=3.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{authordate3}
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{\citep{#1}}
\begin{document}
\noindent topologia de
fluxos bidimensionais através de modernas ferramentas de análise, como
as chamadas estruturas coerentes Lagrangianas \cite{Mathur2007,
  Miranda2013}.
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

And here is a figure with an example of the problem:

[image]

Comment: There is also a white space before the comma, which clearly shouldn't be there.

Comment: I cannot recreate the described behavior with your MWE. When I run it, breaking is as expected: after the comma without additional white space.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very silly bug in `authordate3.bst`, where

```
{\em et~al.\ }\relax
```

appears three times, whereas it should be, instead,

```
{\em et~al\@.}\relax
```

The appearances are at lines 268, 1038 and 1042.

If I copy `authordate3.bst` to the working directory, call it `fix-authordate3.bst`, apply the changes above, replace `\bibliographystyle{authordate3}` in the document with `\bibliographystyle{fix-authordate3}`, run LaTeX, BibTeX and LaTeX, I get the correct output, with no space before the comma.

[image]

Unrelated: avoid doing `\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{\citep{#1}}`. It's unnecessary and you also lose the optional argument.